# twitter bootstrap modal with popover inside

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popover

I'm trying to display a popover inside a modal, everything works greate until i start to work with `show` event from modal.

All the time that popover open, the `show` event from modal is fired, [**live demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WCcQz/1/)

what i'm missing ?

```
// this will open a popover
$("#show-pop-over").on("click", function(){
    var popover = "<div class='popover-content-wrapper' style='display: none;'><a href='#'>Hello ya!</a></div>";
    $("body").append(popover);
    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        placement: "top",
        title: "Title",
        content: function () {
            return $('.popover-content-wrapper').html();
        }
    }).popover("show");
});

// should fire when modal only
$("body").on("show", "#myModal", function(){
    alert('modal on show event');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the show event of the popover is propagating from the `#myModal` div, so the event handler:

```
// should fire when modal only
$("body").on("show", "#myModal", function(){
    alert('modal on show event');
});
```

is firing correctly.

As a workaround, the following will only alert if the modal is shown:

```
// should fire when modal only
$("body").on("show", "#myModal", function(e){
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("modal")) {
       alert('modal on show event');
    }
});
```

Comment: yea, its working now, but can we call this as a bug? Strange behavior since that my `show` event should only fire with `#myModal`.

Comment: Agreed - this is a bug. IMO, the show event should not be propagating like this.